# Javascript eval returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, eval

I am trying to use eval() for calculator i am making, but if when i try this

```
console.log(eval("5.2-5"));
```

It returns

```
0.20000000000000018
```

Why is this happening.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript evaluates "5.2-2" to a floating point number, which precision is not guaranteed.
If you need a fixed precision you could use

```
console.log(eval("5.2-5.0").toFixed(2)):
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how Javascript handles floating point precision. Please see [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) for more information

Short answer: Due to the nature of how computers process floats, this means floating point accuracy actually breaks down past a certain point. This is what you're seeing.

Comment: [Javascript *does* use floats](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) (doubles, actually). It may use integers, but will bail to doubles if math could result in a decimal result.

Comment: Really? I was always under the impression that there was no such thing as an actual float/double, and that the engine always used an integer then converted to something we think of as a float/double? But I could easily be wrong!